# Why do I need \newrefsegment when I already specify refsegment=section?

Tags: biblatex, incompatibility, titlesec

The following works well and shows exactly what I want. I am just wondering
about this: Why do I have to use `\newrefsegment`, if I already specified
`refsegment=section`? I expected everything to work without extra
`\newrefsegment` commands. On the other hand, I can omit `refsegment=section`
and it still works (which is somehow clear).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
style=authoryear,
refsegment=section
]{biblatex}

\defbibheading{subbibheading}{
  \section*{References for Section \ref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}}
}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\newrefsegment
\textcite{reese}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment, heading=subbibheading]

\section{Bar}
\newrefsegment
\textcite{glashow}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment, heading=subbibheading]

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `refsegment=section` is the rough equivalent of setting `\newrefsegment` *before* `\section`. biblatex patches divisional commands this way to ensure that citations in titles don't get assigned to the previous reference segment or section.

Comment: Thanks, Audrey. Is it then possible to increase the counter by 1 globally so that only using `refsegment=section` leads to the correct output? I just tried `\setcounter{therefsegment}{1}` ... but that fails

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To obtain correct label references, you should adapt the examples given in the "Multiple Bibliographies" and "Subdivided Bibliographies" sections of the biblatex documentation. For your case this means omitting `refsegment=section` and either using `\newrefsegment` after `\section` or wrapping the section body in `\begin{refsegment}` and `\end{refsegment}`.

The `refsegment=section` setting is the rough equivalent of issuing `\newrefsegment` *before* `\section`. biblatex patches divisional commands this way to ensure that citations in titles don't get assigned to the previous reference segment or section.

To define the label after the section counter is incremented you can patch the relevant commands in your preamble. For example:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\refsegment}
  {\label{refsegment:\the\c@refsection\the\c@refsegment}}{}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@sect}
  {\label{refsegment:\the\c@refsection\the\c@refsegment}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Although appending patches may interfere with other packages that format titles.

The titlesec package redefines the high-level divisional commands so any low-level patches done by biblatex are ignored; the `refsegment` and `refsection` options won't work at all.

Comment: Hi Audrey. Thanks for helping. I initially thought it works, but I load the package `titlesec` as well, and then it seems to break down. I update the minimal example accordingly. Do you know a solution for that?